# CSS3 Animate it on scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I included css3 animate it on scroll: http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/
the animations are working. the problem is the animations are not working on scroll-reveal. i am using onepage-scroll.js.
this is my body:

```
    <div class="main">

    <section class="home animatedParent">

        <h1 class="animated swing">I am Leon Laci</h1>
        <h3 class="animated swing slower">Front End Web Developer</h2>
        <span class="icon-arrow-down down animated swing slowest"></span>

    </section>

    <section class="about animatedParent">

        <h2 class="animated bounceInRight">About Me</h2>

    </section>

</div>

<script src="js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>
```

this is how the site looks: http://leonlaci.tk/test/

Comment: What is scroll reveal?

Comment: I don't know anything about this plugin, but I have made a jsfiddle here and imported the plugin assets. Is seems to trigger when you scroll horizontally. http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/v8nwp217/

Comment: Can someone recommend plugin that makes animations reveal on scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used lharby link to move about section lower

```
.about {

    margin-top:1200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8nwp217/1/

Vertical scroll also seems to trigger animations well... Try scrolling up and down in the result window.

Comment: The animations are working or scroll, but when i disable onepage scroll js